# Can't get smooth scrolling from fixed menu item to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using the following Javascript on [my web site](http://staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/index.html) to create a smooth scrolling effect when the user clicks the Contact Us link, to scroll to the contact information in the footer. I got this code snippet from a comment by Devin Sturgeon on the [CSS-Tricks post on smooth scrolling](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/). My only guess is that the issue arises from the fact that the anchor link is not in a set position, but in the fixed menu. According to the post, the snippet should work simply by cutting and pasting it in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML for your menu and the target item.  They're essential to whether it will work or not.  Just for completeness, please make sure jQuery is being loaded on your page **before** this code is executed, and that this code is **after** all HTML elements in your `<body>`.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand It worked after moving the code down past all my html elements and adding it to the ready event. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Just putting it at the end of the body is good, because browsers work top-to-bottom.  If your code is at the bottom, it loads it after the HTMl is already parsed and displaying, which keeps the user from staring at a white screen for as long.  It's generally a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')` is returning an empty set so your click handler is not being set on any dom element. The scrolling is being done by the browser using the old fashion anchor tag `<a name="contact">&nbsp;</a>`.

@FakeRainBrigand is right, your document isn't fully loaded when you add your click handler. Just add it to the ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
                || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                   if (target.length) {
                     $('html,body').animate({
                         scrollTop: target.offset().top - 181
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: That took care of it. Thank you!